# Searching arrays of objects with NSPredicate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, search

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

    [displayItems removeAllObjects];  //clear array to ensure no repeat info
    if ([searchText length] == 0) {
        displayItems = (NSMutableArray *)allItems;
    }
    else {
        //search by item category
        NSPredicate *catPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category   
            CONTAINS[cd] %@",searchText];
        [searchable filterUsingPredicate:catPredicate];
        //further search by item name
        NSPredicate *namePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd]
            %@",searchText];
        [searchable filterUsingPredicate:namePredicate];

        displayItems = searchable;
        searchable = (NSMutableArray *)allItems;
    }
    [self.searchResults reloadData];
}
```

This method is part of a simple searchable table view I am trying to create for a larger project.  My code compiles and runs, and when i type something into the search bar the search function appears to work, but then the program crashes as soon as a second letter is typed.  If I type two letters in a row, it throws **'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_*NSArrayI filterUsingPredicate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d6c040'***, but if I type one letter and then hit enter or backspace, it throws this guy **'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_NSArrayI removeAllObjects]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a7f300'** when I type a second letter.

I am pretty new to objective-c, and this has me perplexed.  Any help I could get would be greatly appreciated.... :-/ Still having issues since update.

Comment: searchable = (NSMutableArray *)allItems;
You can't make an NSArray into an NSMutableArray by casting

Comment: searchable is declared as an NSMutableArray, allItems is an NSArray.  I casted it so that I could put all the items for allItems back into the searchable array.  I don't know if this is legal, or if it is what you meant.  Sorry to appear to helpless and confused, but objective-c is new territory for me.  As a side note, i just tried a completely different search algorithm where the line in question and the NSPredicate statements were removed, and I got the same problem except the function didn't even pretend to work.

Comment: Many thanks!  I went back to the NSPredicate solution and replaced the casting statement with addObjectsFromArray and it worked like a charm.  I don't understand why exactly, but It's working.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"One does not simply **cast** NSArray into NSMutableArray and then call NSMutableArray methods on it" - Boromir

Create a mutable copy instead, like this:

```
searchable = [allItems mutableCopy];
```

NOTE: Make sure to release searchable when you are finished with it.

Comment: interesting.  i did not know about mutableCopy.  i do now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use NSMutableArray to call the methods.

NSArray has a method "filteredArrayusingPredicate".

The simple solution is use NSMutableArray.

Comment: Unfortunately, **searchable** and **displayItems** are both NSMutableArrays.  although i think searchable is the only one that ever touches the predicates.